# Unable to clear the displayed output in ShinyApp using actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt, action-button

I'm building a shinyApp on *mtcars data*. I got 2 actionButtons **(Go & Clear).**
The **Go button** is for displaying the output on mainPanel whereas the **Clear button** is for clearing that output. 
My Clear button isn't working due to some unforeseen reason. Can somebody please have a look at my codes. I shall be extremely grateful.

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)

data_table<-mtcars

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),

      actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go"),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Clear")),


    mainPanel(
           DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') )))



#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
                label = "cyl:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
                selected = c('4')) })


  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({

    available <- data_table[c(data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl ), "disp"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = 'All') })


  thedata <- eventReactive(input$go,{

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]


    if(input$disp != 'All'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }

    data_table
 })


 # thedata <- eventReactive(input$reset,{
 #   data_table<-NULL
 # })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                   options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE,
                                  dom = 'Brtip'  ),
                   {     
                     thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()
                   })
 })}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't analyze your script completly, but i can see that it doesn't call the second button at all (**Clear**). You made an *eventReactive()* using **input$go** for the first button to make the plot, but you need to call **input$reset** too if you want to make it work.

Comment: Hi mate, sorry i forgot to put that part, i have added that with hashtag. Please have a look again. Thanks :)